# How to handle Console Application Close button event

Tags: console

I have a console application which communicating with WCF service on startup and after som computation we are entering some data in sql database. and in console app we are handling enter key to close the application and at the time of closing Application i am cleaning relevant data from Database. but It fails when some close the console application using mouse to click on close icon.(Instantly its close).

Please let me know that how to handle Close button event and also ctrl+f4.

The code is below:

Private m_ControllerID As String = String.Empty 
Sub Main()

```
    HostControllerService()
```

End Sub

```
Private Sub HostControllerService()        

    m_ControllerID = RegisterMe()

    Console.WriteLine("Retention Controller Service is running...")

    Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> key to exit and UnRegister the service.")
    Console.ReadLine()
    UnRegisterMe(m_ControllerID)

End Sub

Private Function RegisterMe() As String

    'Code snippet to Save data In database.

End Function

Private Sub UnRegisterMe(ByVal m_ControllerID As String)

    'Cleaning the data from Database.

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you ready for WinApi (C++ example) solution?